# Turn on keyboard backlight from command line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My main keyboard broke, so I extracted it's LED with circuit board. I'm trying to use this LED to illuminate my desk but I'm unable to turn on its light. At the old keyboard I would turn on the lights pressing `fn + SL` but my new keyboard does not have the fn key. Is it possible to simulate this command through terminal? I noticed that the two keyboards are kinda synced, when I turn on num lock at my new keyboard the circuit board from the other also turns on.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the command `xset led on` in the terminal. Or since they appear to be synced, you could try pressing `fn + SL` on your working one.

Update: 
You can set that you do not need to hold the `fn` key through the UEFI/BIOS. [Here](https://youtu.be/5Q11yNBd7X4) is a video to show you how.

Comment: As I said, there's no ```fn``` key in my new keyboard, and ```xset led on``` just turns on scroll lock